# Scala - Update RDD with another Map

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm trying to update an RDD with more information from another Map....I wrote this but is not working.

Where:

LocalCurrencies is a Sequence of Currency class

rdd: RDD[String, String]

```
...
val localCurrencies = Await.result(CurrencyDAO.currencies, 30 seconds)

//update ISO3
rdd.map(r => r.updated("currencyiso3", localCurrencies.find(c => c.CurrencyId ==   
rdd.get("currencyid")).get.ISO3))

//Update exponent
rdd.map(r => r.updated("exponent", localCurrencies.find(c => c.CurrencyId == 
rdd.get("currencyid")).get.Exponent))
```

Any suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: LocalCurrencies is Map of type what?

Comment: Also, what is the type of rdd? Is it Rdd[String]?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Sample data is always welcome but you can start with the types of all variables.

Comment: @MukrramRahman - updated, please excuse my mistake, am a scala newbie

Comment: @zero323: I updated my question, thanks

Comment: `RDD` has just one type parameter, you can't have `RDD[String, String]`. And if you mean `RDD[(String, String)]`, then `r` in `map` will have type `(String, String)` and no `updated` method.

Comment: If by "is not working" you mean "does not compile" or "throws an exception", always include the error. If you mean "doesn't give the result you expect", include the input data, the expected result, and the actual result.

Comment: Looks like might worth looking at IndexedRDD: https://github.com/amplab/spark-indexedrdd...

Answer (score 2):

`map` doesn't *modify* an RDD, it creates a new one (the same applies to every Spark transformation). If you don't actually do anything with this new RDD, Spark won't even bother creating it. So you want to write

```
val rdd1 = rdd.map(...).map(...) // better to combine two `map`s into one
```

and work with `rdd1` from then one (you can still use `rdd` as well, if needed). This isn't necessarily the only error, but you'll still need to fix it.